# how to convert string to byte array in Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to download a file in classic ASP.
Please find the below code

```
set fileDownloadResponse = WebService_FileDownload(FileUri.Value)
Response.ContentType = admindata("FileType")//type getting from SQL column
Response.Addheader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & FileName & """"
Response.BinaryWrite(fileDownloadResponse.value)//**fileDownloadResponse.value**
```

I am returning as `Byte[]` from code but when it is coming to ASP page, it is showing as a string...I want to convert the string to Byte Array and pass that array into `Response.BinaryWrite(need to pass byte)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [ADO Stream Object](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_stream.asp)

```
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Response.Buffer = False
Dim objStream
Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
objStream.Open
' depends on what fileDownloadResponse is 
' you might need to use .Read(), .ReadText() or .LoadFromFile()
objStream.ReadText fileDownloadResponse.value 
Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown" ' what kind of file it is?
Response.Addheader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & FileName & """"
Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read
objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private HttpResponseMessage DownloadFileResponse( HttpStatusCode statusCode, Byte[] ContentArray )
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();              
            response.StatusCode = statusCode;              
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent( ContentArray );//here just convert into byte array content and in Response.BinaryWrite (content) pass this content here to get as byte to doqnlaod it.
            return response;      
        }
```